# How reconnect clients sockets to my server if my server restarts

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp, server, client

I'm trying to make a client-server connection using sockets.

It basically works pretty well; only one problem is when I close and re-open my server on server computer the clients won't reconnect

This is my client code :

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
        Public Delegate Sub MessageReceivedEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MessageReceivedEventArgs)
        Public Delegate Sub ClientConnectedEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ClientConnectedEventArgs)
        Public Event MessageReceived As MessageReceivedEventHandler
        Public Event ClientConnected As ClientConnectedEventHandler
        Public Buffer As Byte()
        Public Shared Client As TcpClient
        Dim Port As Integer = 5050
    Dim host As String = "computer name"
    Dim KEY As String = "mykey"

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim T As New Thread(AddressOf run)
        T.Start()
    End Sub


    Private Sub run()
        ' Connect to the server'
        Client = New TcpClient(host, Port)
        Dim T As New Thread(AddressOf Receiver, 10) 
        T.Start()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function StringToByte(ByVal STR As String) As Byte()
        Return System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(STR)
    End Function
    Public Shared Function ByteToString(ByVal BYS As Byte()) As String
        Return System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(BYS)
    End Function
    Public Sub Data(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal Data As MessageReceivedEventArgs) Handles Me.MessageReceived
        Dim info As Byte() = Data.Message
        Dim Client As Socket = Data.clientSocket
        Dim ID As String = Data.Sender
        Dim Arr As String() = Split(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(info), "mykey")
        Try
            Select Case Arr(0)

                Case "MSG"
                MsgBox(Arr(1))
                           End Select
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error Detected in Data Client :" & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Sub Receiver()
        Dim M As New MemoryStream
        Try
                If Client.Available > 0 Then
                    ReDim Buffer(Client.Available - 1)
                    Client.Client.Receive(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None)
                    M.Write(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)
                    If System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(M.ToArray).Contains("EOF") Then
                        Dim Data As Byte() = (M.ToArray).Remove(ConfigTcp.ENDOFPACKET)
                        Dim Msg As New MessageReceivedEventArgs
                        Msg.Message = Data
                        Msg.clientSocket = Client.Client
                        Msg.Sender = Client.Client.Handle.ToString()
                        RaiseEvent MessageReceived(Me, Msg)
                        M.Dispose()
                        M = New MemoryStream
                    End If
                End If
                Thread.Sleep(1)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error Detected :" & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Public Shared Sub Send(ByVal sock As Socket, ByVal s As String)
            Send(sock, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s))
        End Sub
        Private Shared Sub Send(ByVal sock As Socket, ByVal b As Byte())
            Try
                Dim Memory As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
                Dim CB As Byte() = b
                Memory.Write(CB, 0, CB.Length)
                Memory.Write(ConfigTcp.ENDOFPACKET, 0, ConfigTcp.ENDOFPACKET.Length)
                sock.Send(Memory.ToArray, 0, Memory.Length, SocketFlags.None)
                Memory.Dispose()
            Catch x As Exception
            End Try
        End Sub
    End Class
    Public Class MessageReceivedEventArgs
        Inherits EventArgs
        Public Sender As String
        Public clientSocket As Socket
        Public Message As Byte()
    End Class
    Public Class ClientConnectedEventArgs
        Inherits EventArgs
        Public clientID As String
        Public clientSocket As Socket
    End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client needs to handle disconnects and reconnect if needed.

To accomplish this, you can catch a `SocketException` and see why the socket was closed.

Depending on the exception you can run a method to have your client reconnect.

```
Public Sub DoReconnect()
    Dim SecondsToWait as Integer=1
    Do
        Try
            Client = New TcpClient(host, Port)
            Exit Do
        Catch SockEx as SocketException
            'TODO: decide whether to attempt reconnection or exit
        Catch Ex as Exception
            'TODO: Most likely should terminate the program here
            Console.WriteLine(Ex.ToString())
            Exit Do
        End Try 
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(SecondsToWait*1000) 
        SecondsToWait <<=1 ' Exponential Back Off Time
    Loop   
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for being noob but what's the best way to handle the disconnects

Comment: Like is said, In your try catch statements, where applicable, call DoReconnect()

Answer (score 0):

@Alexander Higgins
I tried something like this but seems that  **SocketException** happens only before opening the server for the first time.If I close the server it and re-open it, it doesn't **catch SocketException**

```
   Public Sub DoReconnect()
    re:
            Thread.Sleep(1000)
            Try
                Client = New TcpClient(host, Port)
                Dim T As New Thread(AddressOf Receiver, 10)
                T.IsBackground = True
                T.Start()
            Catch SockEx As SocketException
                MsgBox("SocketException " + SockEx.Message)
                GoTo re

            Catch Ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Exception " + Ex.Message)

            End Try


        End Sub
        Private Sub run()
            DoReconnect()
        End Sub
```